# Почему gdb отображает инструкции подобным образом?

Tags: ассемблер, gdb, reverse-engineering

Есть типичное начало функции. Так оно отображается в `gdb`:

```
   0x00401280 <+10>:    push   %ebp
   0x00401281 <+11>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
```

Интересует вопрос: почему именно `mov    %esp,%ebp`? 
По идее, функция должна назначить `esp` на место `ebp`. Следовательно должно быть `mov    %ebp,%esp`. Ведь синтаксис выглядит так: `MOV ПРИЁМНИК, ИСТОЧНИК`
 Собственно, так это и выглядит во всех отладчиках, с этой же программой. Такой порядок отображения присущ только `gdb`? Если да, то какова причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это стиль синтаксиса под названием AT&T. Он используется в GDB по умолчанию, и одной из его отличительных особенностей является, как вы заметили, порядок операндов. В AT&T источник идет первым операндом, а приемник - вторым.

Вы можете переключиться на привычный стиль с помощью [set dissassembly-flavor](http://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/set_disassembly-flavor).